# How to create a TFS2010 Team Build Template for getting source and call msbuild.exe

Tags: msbuild, tfsbuild, workflow-foundation

I have a build.proj, that is a MSBuild file and can be run locally.

All I need from TFS is

1. Get the sources from TFS Source Control.
2. Call "MSBuild.exe /t:Deploy".
3. Update the build status based on the result of MSBuild.

I have tried to make a template combining the DefaultTemplate.xaml and UpgradeTemplate.xaml.

But so far, no luck :-(

Can someone help me make this template?

Comment: Add your support for a dedicated Visual Studio ALM Q&A Stack Exchange site by commiting to the proposal. 
http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/15894/visual-studio-alm?referrer=vtx1N5_bjYysH8mQCaDCxQ2

Comment: You are going to have to give more information? Do you have the build output? What version of Visual Studio Team Foundation Server?

Comment: VS 2010, TFS 2010.

The problem is that MS change the build in TFS from MSBuild to WF? So I need a simple WF Template that get the lastest sources and call my custom MS build file.

Answer (score 0):

If you select the upgrade template that comes out of the box when you create a new TFS project with 2010, you can supply your old TFS2008 proj (MSBuild) file without problems. Please read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd647553.aspx for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You should use DefaultTemplate. I had the same problem and I solved it this way.
You can do it using UpgradeTempate also, but using DefaultTemplate was easier for me.

On Process section follow these steps:

1. Select Default template
2. Add your project into Items To Build collection
3. Set MSBuild Arguments (Advanced section) to "/t:Deploy"

I have MSBuild project file for running builds locally. This script is used also for sever builds. I have three MSBuild projects in Items To Build collection. One for PreBuild step (some checks before build is executed), main build script used also for local build and the last script for additional post build tasks (deploy process). I'm setting additional MSBuild propertires like IncrementalBuild and ServerBuild properties in MSBuild Arguments.